# VBA concatenate two ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to concatenate two ranges in excel using VBA so each cell in range1 concatenates all cells in range2 until cell A is null. Please see below:

```
Range1(column A): Range2(column B):
50703, 50702      52797, 52848

Concatenate(column C):
50703-52797, 50703-52848, 50702-52797, 50702-52848
```

Comment: Were you going to show your own effort toward a solution?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to find all permutations of both ranges of cells using column A cell values as the first part of the results. What is the total number of cells used in the A and B columns?

Comment: What do you plan to use the value of column C for after you've got that result?

Comment: jsheeran - I have a list of 54 values in column A and a list of 59 values in column B which will take a while to manually concatenate (3186 values). The data will be loaded into a different system.

Comment: Jeeped - I don't have any code written yet for this. Did some research online but couldn't find anything apart from concatenating two ranges which (line by line) is not what I'm trying to do here. What I want is for each cell in range1 concatenate with all cells in range2, then move to the next cell until cell in range1 is null.

Comment: 5202456 - that'd be 54 values in range1 and 59 values in range2 = total of 3186 values in culumn C

Comment: @Cornel Ciobanu If you were to compare the efficiency of my answer, which works and which you first accepted, to the efficiency of the now accepted answer (from 5202456), you would see that my code is far superior. Moreover, the now accepted answer doesn't use fully qualified references, which is best practice in VBA coding, so you might want to reconsider here.

Comment: Thanks @Miqi180 - both codes work just fine! Thanks both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will insert all the **combinations** of values in column A and B into column C and concatenate them with a hyphen:

```
Sub combinations()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim valsColA As Variant, valsColB As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combinations") ' change sheet name, if necessary

        valsColA = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Value
        valsColB = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Value

        For i = LBound(valsColA) To UBound(valsColA)
            For j = LBound(valsColB) To UBound(valsColB)
                n = n + 1
                .Cells(n, 3).Value = valsColA(i, 1) & "-" & valsColB(j, 1)
            Next j
        Next i

    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with, although @Miqi180 got there first:

```
Sub ABPerm()

Dim Acol As Integer
Dim Bcol As Integer
Dim RowNumA As Integer
Dim RowNumB As Integer
Dim RowNumC As Integer

Acol = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Bcol = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

RowNumA = 1
RowNumB = 1
RowNumC = 1

For a = 1 To Acol

    For b = 1 To Bcol
        Range("C" & RowNumC).Value = Range("A" & RowNumA).Value & "-" & Range("B" & RowNumB).Value
        RowNumB = RowNumB + 1
        RowNumC = RowNumC + 1
    Next b

    RowNumB = 1
    RowNumA = RowNumA + 1

Next a

End Sub
```

Comment: @5202456 These are combinations, not permutations, so your procedure name, ABPerm, doesn't really make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim rng         As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
rng.Offset(, 2).Value = Evaluate("If(Row(1:" & rng.Rows.Count & ")," & rng.Address(, , , True) & " & " & "-" & rng.Offset(, 1).Address(, , , True) & ")")
End Sub
```